# Rest Client Debugger test upload images

Tags: rest

I m stuck on the following scenario, I do hope some who did it successfully for the past could help me on this problem.

I m using REST CLIENT DEBUGGER which is used to perform HTTP GET and POST to get the desire result. I m working on android and require to upload image from my phone to the server but I not sure how to test the result using this REST CLIENT DEBUGGER written by Chao.

IDE I used: Titanium
Situation:Upload an image from phone to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some sort of Base64 encoder and encode your image.  A quick search turned up:
http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Copy the text the encoder provides into the BODY of your POST to the web service.  Decode the image on the server from base 64 into the image format that you want.

I can't remember who I got this code from, but it wasn't my source (C# Source).

```
private Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
        {
            Image image = null;
            try
            {
                // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
                byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
                  imageBytes.Length);

                // Convert byte[] to Image
                ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                writeException(ex);
            }

            return image;
        }
```

I then take the image and convert it to a png, which is relatively easy in C#.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your reply. If do like what u says, I used file put content function and put the parameter(location filename,decoded image).. but the problem is the result of content is unreadable. let say i create an image call testing.jpg but when I open the image, it says not supported image or not bitmap. any idea what cause this?

Comment: If you want to make sure the data came through ok, try pasting it back into the conversion site and see if you get the same result back before the conversion.  Then you just need to figure out how to create the image correctly in your language of choice.

Comment: Hi 1 question, is it possible getimagesize perform on decoded base64 images?

Comment: Are you saving the images to the server?  I imagine you could query the file's properties after you save the file to the server's hard drive.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for your reply. I did it. I save a temporary file and getimagesize. Thanks a lot for your comment. really helpful especially the first reply .cheers